# Mysql status shows "mysql stop/waiting" and after some time, it stops

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have ubuntu server with apache, mysql mysql installed.

When I start mysql it starts proper, but after starting, when we check mysql status, it shows "mysql stop/waiting".

And after some time, mysql stops automatically.

Please help me to resolve this mysql issue.